# Remote Debug in VS 2015 to Windows Server 2012 doesn't work

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I have followed all instruction in order to Configure the remote debugger as a service on the server (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).
I am using Visual studio 2015 on my local computer.
The server is Windows Server 2012 R2.

i have tried 2 methods of remote debugging:

1) by attaching to a process. The process is attached successfully but i cannot set a breakpoint. I get an error: 
[see error adding breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioIpn.jpg).
I followed all tips for loading the symbols - but still, nothing works.

2) by going to Properties=> Debug => user remote machine (as explained in the tutorial I linked above). When i do this, i get an error: access denied. I followed all tips to fix this, and there is no firewall on the server, but it just wont work.

Please Help! I've spent hours and hours trying to get this to work, and without this - my project can't go live.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

1) in remote debugger goto tools=> options=> choose: No authentication & allow any user to debug.

2) in local computer goto debug=> options=> debugging => general and make sure that there is NO tick on "Use Managed compatibility Mode"

3) when attaching the process make sure to choose: Transport remote!

Answer (score 0):

I am always going with 1). But before I attach to the process on remote server I build the project and copy all files (including pdbs) to the remote destination (I backup the original files of course). It worked each time. Sometimes VS does not show that the symbols have been loaded but when the code reach my breakpoint it will pause on it in the VS.

Comment: I copied all files to the remote destination (that's located in exactly the same path as my local computer - as requested in the tutorial), and tried to run, but code will not stop at breakpoint :(
PS - i also prefer option #1...

Comment: @Abigail That's strange. What kind of application is it? Are you sure that you have replaced correct files?

Comment: I found the answer - see my answer above!